# wrong saving with one to many relationship .net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have one to many relationships between Appointments(Services_Id FK) and Services tables, When I Post new appointment it is supposed to insert Services_Id in appointment table but it creates a new record in Services table

Controller:

```
  // GET
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        AspNetUser aspNetUser = new AspNetUser();
        ConfigureViewModel(aspNetUser.ToString());
        List<Services> servicelist = db.Services.ToList();
        ViewBag.servicelist = new SelectList(servicelist, "Id", "Name");

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Appointments appointments)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            appointments = new Appointments()
            {

                AspNetUser = appointments.AspNetUser,
                service = appointments.service,

            };
            db.Appointments.Add(appointments);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    public JsonResult GetServicesByUserId(string Id)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        List<Services> StateList = db.Services.Where(x => x.aspNetUser_Id == Id).ToList();
        return Json(StateList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

View :

```
 @Html.DropDownList("AspNetUser", ViewBag.userslist as SelectList, "--Select --", new { @class = "form-control" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.service.Name, new SelectList(" "), "--Select Service--", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "dropdownServices" })

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#AspNetUser").change(function () {
            $.get("/Appointments/GetServicesByUserId", { Id: $("#AspNetUser").val() }, function (data) {
                $("#dropdownServices").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                    $("#dropdownServices").append("<option value='" + row.aspNetUser_Id + "'>" + row.Name + "</option>")
                });
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Isn't that one-to-many? If that's many-to-many you need a junction table between Services and Appointment which could be AppointmentServices.

Comment: Yes, It's is one to many, I edited it

Answer (score 0):

Is `service_id` explicitly mentioned in your model? If so I believe you'll your desired output by assigning the value by `Services_Id = appointments.service_Id` instead of passing the whole `appointments.service` object.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Appointments appointments)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      appointments = new Appointments()
      {
         AspNetUser = appointments.AspNetUser,

         // accesss use the service Id instead of passing the whole object
         service_Id = appointments.service.Id,
      };

      db.Appointments.Add(appointments);
      db.SaveChanges();
   }

   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: No it's not in my model , it is like this :
        public virtual Services service { get; set; }

Comment: @Ms.Fatima Have you tried the solution above? Are you open to adding a ServiceId in your Appointments model?

Comment: @Ms.Fatima see my new answer below.

Comment: Yes I tried your solution but the problem now the  service_Id type is Int and appointments.service.Id(namesapace.Data.Services) so I got an error :Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'Startupfuels.Data.Services'

Comment: still not passing to the controller https://imgur.com/9qwBAc2

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem, you're suppose to use model.service.Id in your model DropDownListFor.

In your controller you are already passing the correct values to your select list;

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   AspNetUser aspNetUser = new AspNetUser();
   ConfigureViewModel(aspNetUser.ToString());
   List<Services> servicelist = db.Services.ToList();
   ViewBag.servicelist = new SelectList(servicelist, "Id","Name");

   return View();
}
```

But in your view, you should use model.service.Id and not Name.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.service.Id, new SelectList(" "), "--Select Service--", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "dropdownServices" })
```

Then in your controller, retain this;

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Appointments appointments)
{
   Service dbService = db.Services.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.Id == appointments.service.Id);

   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      newAppointments = new Appointments()
      {
         AspNetUser = appointments.AspNetUser,
         service = dbService
      };

      db.Appointments.Add(appointments);
      db.SaveChanges();
   }

   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution above but ModelState is given False and nothing save

Comment: @Ms.Fatima thats odd, it should be working if youre using `service = appointments.service`

Comment: @Ms.Fatima will you debug the code and see if the appoinments.service.id is being passed to the controller? and include a screenshot in your question

Comment: @Ms.Fatima I updated the answer, can you try with another variable name for appointments? I used newAppointments. If that doesnt work, upload your code in github and link it to me.

Comment: appointments.service.id is passing to controller now, but still saving as a new in Service table instead of just passing the id to appointment table, I need to convert model type to int this line : service = appointments.service.Id,

Comment: @Ms.Fatima I updated the controller post code, I figured let's get service from the database first and store it to an object which we will use in appointments.